# Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart

I just want to ask for possible library that will result with this kind of stacked bar chart. I can't seem to find any that matches this. Thank you for any suggestions that you can give.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple libraries to implement charts like this. You can directly use D3.js to implement above chart.

Another way using fluentUi chart - charting library (https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/tree/master/packages/react-charting)

You can directly install this package to your project.
You just need to send required props to the chart.
(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/get-started#add-to-existing-project)